# $("p:first"); VS document.querySelector("p");

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I don't get it.
`$("p:first")` selects the first `p` element. Same goes to `document.querySelector("p");`

So why can't just use one of it?

I hope this is not a stupid question but I really need to get this clear.

**EDIT**

When can and can't we use each of these of two?

Comment: One is jQuery, a library. The other is plain javascript

Comment: `document.querySelector("p");` is plain javascript, use this if you don't want to include jQuery. `$("p:first")` is jQuery. Whats your exact question?

Comment: If you're using jquery elsewhere, use `$("p:first")` for succinct coding.  If you're not using jquery, then use the verbose version.  Also known as "vanilla javascript".

Comment: Worth noting that `document.querySelector` didn't exist at all in (main) browsers before 2010 (or so) and so after that would have taken a while to migrate, while the jquery version was immediately available in 2006 (without needing to wait for users to migrate to newer browsers).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two statements. `document.querySelector("p")` is plain javascript and `$("p:first")` is using jQuery

jQuery is a JavaScript Library that simplifies JavaScript programming. Its syntax is very simple and it makes everything much easier.

You can check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/) to learn more about jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to take must performance use `document.querySelector("p");`
About this question I suggest to see this website http://vanilla-js.com/